# Get original prototype object within a function given a variable stored in the original prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, prototype

I have a prototype object that holds an array of objects.  One of the array objects is passed to a function and i need to access the original object from which it came ...

Are there any ways to do this without knowing the name of the original object?

Example:

```
function ObjectA {
    this.attribute[0] = new ObjectB;
}

ObjectB.prototype.func = function (s) {
    //I have the attribute[0] (an object) here, i need to access A 
      from it
}

var objectA = new ObjectA(data);
objectA.attribute[0].func(3);
```

Comment: Maybe you need to edit your question to improve the code part?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Your question's code does not show any prototypes being set up.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You'd have to pass `ObjectA` or `objectA` (not sure what you want) to the function.

Comment: Looks pretty much like your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127198/accessing-an-objects-parent-or-instance-given-a-sub-object which both has an answer and is marked as a duplicate.  Please stop asking the same question over and over.  It's already been answered MULTIPLE times the best I can tell.

Comment: @jfriend00 Nope. Neither were answered with a solution.  The solution i was looking for is marked below.  Thanks

Comment: Uhhh, I absolutely answered your previous question.  I told you there that there was no way to get a container from an object in that container (which is what you asked) unless you set a property that names the container or unless you pass the parent to the function where you wanted to use it.  That was an answer to the EXACT question you asked there.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you show me where I mentioned anything related to a container in the previous question?  You answered the question, yes.. The answer you provided wasn't helpful.

Comment: Uhhh, your second sentence: ***"One of the array objects is passed to a function and i need to access the original object from which it came ".***  Sounds exactly like the previous question to me.

Comment: My original answer wasn't helpful?  I answered EXACTLY what you asked.  Apparently you didn't ask what you wanted to ask because I answered what you wrote and the people that marked it a dup thought the same thing as I.

Comment: @jfriend00 And, like I said, your answer was not helpful.  Someone else provided the right solution.

Comment: The rules here are we answer what you ask the best we can.  Not much we can do if you ask the wrong question or are unclear about what you meant to ask.  I answered exactly what you asked.

Comment: @jfriend00 Obviously it wasn't if somebody else provided the right solution

Comment: @jfriend00 Exactly, it's not my fault you didn't understand my question

Comment: There is absolutely NOTHING in that previous question that would lead to this solution.

Comment: Bye.  No point in helping you any more.  If you write clearer questions, you will get better help.

Comment: @jfriend00 If there was nothing in the previous question that would lead to this solution why did you accuse me of asking the SAME question over and over again? Are you blind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You'd have to pass `ObjectA` or `objectA` (not sure what you want) to the function.

That means the function has to accept that value as an argument:

```
ObjectB.prototype.func = function (s, target) {
    // do whatever you want with `target`
}
```

and you'd have to call it with

```
objectA.attribute[0].func(3, objectA);
```

However, you could also replace the object's `func` method with another one that will always pass `ObjectA` to it:

```
function ObjectA {
   const self = this;
   const objB = new ObjectB;

   objB.func = function(s) {
     ObjectB.prototype.func.call(this, s, self);
   };

   this.attribute[0] = objB();
}
```

and you could keep calling the function as

```
objectA.attribute[0].func(3);
```

---

You are not explaining why you want to do this, so these solutions might or might not be overly complex or suitable for what you are trying to do.

Comment: The second solution you posted here pointed me in the right direction and i got it working.  Really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question's code did not show any prototypes being set up. If I understand what you are asking correctly, you are just trying to store an instance of one object as a property of another. This is what you are looking for:

```js
// This is the not a prototype. It's just a regular constructor
// function that can be used to create instances of objects
function ObjectA(){
  this.someProp = "test";
}

// This is the object that will gain access to the other's properties
function ObjectB() {
    // You can't populate an array unless you have one first:
    this.attribute = [];
    
    // Now, you can populate it. But, you aren't utilizing prototypes
    // with this code, you are just storing an instance of an object
    // in an instance property of this one:
    this.attribute[0] = new ObjectA();
}

// You need an instance to work with:
var B = new ObjectB();

// Now that new instance can get you properties of another object it
// is storing as a property:
console.log(B.attribute[0].someProp);
```

For details on how prototypical inheritance in JavaScript works, see **[this other post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028673/shorthand-for-object-create-with-multiple-properties/41028806#41028806)** that explains that.

Comment: Assigning to `ObjectB.prototype.func` is setting up the prototype, isn't it? I guess the OP just omitted the declaration of `ObjectB`.

Comment: I edited the code block.  In this case, there would be another function that takes B.attribute[0].someProp as a parameter.  Inside that same function, i need access to B.  I only get access the someProp

Comment: @FelixKling The original post didn't contain that code.

Comment: You posted after the OP's edit but I guess you were still seeing the old version. Race condition `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` .

Comment: @FelixKling Yup!